# Tutorial on OpenGL texture formats

Tags: opengl, textures

Looking at the documentation [glGetTexImage()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml), one can see that there are plenty of available texture formats.

GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, and GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z

I've only used GL_TEXTURE_2D for the time being.

Is there any place / documentation where one can learn about these other formats ?

PS : and yes, of course, i've googled for it, results are pretty poor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most comprehensive information can usually be found by reading OpenGL extension specifications:

GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_3D:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_object.txt
(slightly antiquated)

GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rectangle.txt

GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_XXX
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_cube_map.txt

GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt

Comment: Thanks for the links. I already read some of them, although having them well organised in a single post is a great plus. My only comment is that "comprehensive" is probably not the word i would have used for these docs. "Written by experts for experts" seems more appropriate.